# Can I cut a keyboard in half?

Tags: keyboard, wired

I have a keyboard I have taken apart and I only use the number pad. My question is, can I cut off the rest?

My keyboard:

[image: My keyboard]

Comment: I'm worried it would cut off the circuit.

Comment: You can alternatively buy a keypad keyboard for as much as 10$: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B01E8TTWZ2/ref=zgm_bs_2998471011_1?ie=UTF8&sr=1-1&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65

Answer (score 3):

There is an old type of keyboards looks like this one below
[image]
As you can see everything on one PCB it will take time to trace every wire! and the components everywhere..

The second type looks like this one below
[image]

They separate the IC from the switches, before you cut it in half be sure where is the GND wire!

Check this [Article](http://runawaybrainz.blogspot.com.tr/2012/01/hack-reverse-engineer-and-re-purpose.html)

[image]

Comment: **From Poster**: Would I be able to put something on the rest of it that would remve it's sensetivity? That way I might be able to fold it in hal or something :)

Answer (score 0):

You could, only after verifying there is no circuit in the other part. I seen this tried before and it did not work, so I would only give you small % in terms of success.